# How to make auto complete show selected item when page initialize

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I have an (primeng) autocomplete control of streets which is populate correctly, binded and act as needed. I have one problem - I can't make the control display the 
model selected street name, when the page is being initiated.
see my code:

```
<p-autoComplete formControlName="StreetID" [dropdown]="true" 
[suggestions]="streetsList" [field] ="'StreetName'" (completeMethod)="searchStreet($event)" [disabled]=!frm.value.CityID (onSelect)="onSelect($event)"></p-autoComplete>
```

How can I make the autocomplete show the selected item ?

Comment: Why dont you use [(ngModel)]?

Comment: I'm using reactive form. As far as I know - you can't use ngModel, when you bind to a form control

Comment: The issue was raised and answered by me in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324034/how-to-bind-auto-complete-selected-value-to-form-control-name